# Unable to fetch SMS which having text in address

Tags: android, sms, android-contentresolver

I am trying to fetch SMS's which start with TM-,ID-, AX-, AD- but I am getting sms's only which having number.

I am not able to receive any sms which will have text in address.

Here is my code :

```
    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
String[] projection = new String[]{"_id", "address", "date", "body", "person", "type"};
m_SMSCursor =context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, projection, null,null,null);   
if(m_SMSCursor.moveToFirst())

{

    // Read each row from cursor and store it into the database
    do {
        // Extract fields from cursor
        final String number = m_SMSCursor.getString(1);
        final long date = m_SMSCursor.getLong(2);
        final String body = m_SMSCursor.getString(3);
        final String person = m_SMSCursor.getString(4);
        final int type = m_SMSCursor.getInt(5);

        try {
            // Insert call log into database
            long l;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // create object for CallLogAdapter
                    SMSDataAdapter objSmsDataAdapter = new SMSDataAdapter(
                            context);
                    // open the database
                    objSmsDataAdapter = objSmsDataAdapter.Open();
                    try {


                        boolean isVMPresent = number.startsWith("VM-");
                        boolean isLMPresent = number.startsWith("LM-");
                        boolean isTMPresent = number.startsWith("TM-");
                        boolean isVKPresent = number.startsWith("VK-");
                        boolean isIXPresent = number.startsWith("IX-");
                        boolean isADPresent = number.startsWith("AD-");
                        boolean isAXPresent = number.startsWith("AX-");
                        boolean isBWPresent = number.startsWith("BW-");
                        boolean isIDPresent = number.startsWith("ID-");
                        boolean isIMPresent = number.startsWith("IM-");
                        Log.i(TAG, "Number1 : " + number + " body1 : " + body + " peron : " + person + " type : " + type);
                        if (isVMPresent || isLMPresent || isTMPresent || isVKPresent || isIXPresent || isADPresent || isAXPresent || isBWPresent || isIDPresent || isIMPresent) {


                            long lNumberOfEntry = objSmsDataAdapter.Insert(number, body, date, DATA_NOT_ANALYZED);

                        }

                    } catch (SQLException e1) {


                    } finally {
                        // Close the database
                        objSmsDataAdapter.Close();
                    }

                }
            }).start();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            return FAILURE;

        }
    } while (m_SMSCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

But I am able to fetch all sms except which having text in address. I am able fetch sms's which having number in address.

Please give me hint or reference.

Comment: this is for new incoming SMS or the ones in inbox?

Comment: not for new incoming but which are in inbox

Comment: You code is very inefficient as you are trying to do everything under the loop. Use the cursor loop first to get all the data and then do other comparisons

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to get all data in a list first and then access the number by smsList.getNumber()

```
   List<SMSData> smsList = new ArrayList<SMSData>();

   Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
   Cursor c= getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null);
   startManagingCursor(c);

   // Read the sms data and store it in the list
   if(c.moveToFirst()) {
       for(int i=0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
           SMSData sms = new SMSData();
           sms.setBody(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString());
           sms.setNumber(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
           smsList.add(sms);

           c.moveToNext();
       }
   }
   c.close();
```

SMSData:

```
public class SMSData {

 // Number from witch the sms was send
private String number;
// SMS text body
private String body;

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
   this.number = number;
}

public String getBody() {
   return body;
}  

public void setBody(String body) {
   this.body = body;
  }

}
```

Comment: You contains() instead of starts with

Comment: No. Not yet. Still searching for solution.